# Could I centralize batch files more efficiently?

Tags: windows, batch

I am new to the world of batch scripting so please forgive what may appear as basic questions. I am learning as I get assigned different jobs and I am a huge proponent of automation where possible. I have several batch files that perform several tasks. Each of these files had their paths hard-coded e.g. c:\temp. d:\data, etc in the batch file. Initially I moved these to a text file I could call from a batch file e.g.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%R in (config.txt) do ( 
if %%R==bdata set bdata=%%S
if %%R==cdata set cdata=%%S
)
```

The config.txt file contains these values

```
bdata=c:\temp
cdata=d:\data
```

I realized that each time I would need to create a new variable, I would need to update the config.txt file as well the config.bat files.

I decided I would move all the values to just the config.bat file as follows

```
set bdata=c:\temp
set cdata=d:\data
```

I then updated each of the existing batch files to call the variables rather than the hard-coded paths. I also added the following lines of code to each batch file except config.bat. The only additional line added to the config.bat file is `@echo off`.

```
@echo off    

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

call config.bat
```

I then have another batch file that centralizes calling all the batch files in sequence. The name of this batch file is start.bat. The reason I am using `start /wait` is because there have been instances of where the `delete.bat` runs before `compress.bat` has had an opportunity to finish.

```
start /wait compress.bat
start /wait validate.bat
start /wait delete.bat
```

**Questions**

1. Is this the best way to centralize values and if not, what is a better way?
2. Do I need to specify `setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion` in all the existing batch files?
3. Do all the batch files have to have @echo off or is it sufficient for just the config.bat file?
4. Is `start /wait` the best way to call multiple files? Can I pass values from one batch file to another using the said command?
5. All the batch files have different functions e.g. move, delete, etc however use %%a or %%b. Is this okay?

For example

The `validate.bat` file has the code

```
for %%a in (%bdata%\*.*) do if "%%~xa" == "" move /Y "%bdata%\%%~xa" "%bdata%\%done%"
```

and the `delete.bat file` has the code

```
for %%a in (%bdata%\*.*) do if "%%~xa" == ".txt" del "%%a"
```

Comment: i would recommend you to extend beyond batch files using WScript...this will enable to you to incorporate much advanced stuff into the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It’s not bad, but if the external batch-files are simple, you could just put their code in the main batch-file as subroutines and just call their labels. For example:

   ```
   These four files:

   ::main.bat:
   @echo off
   call compress.bat …
   call validate.bat …
   call delete.bat …

   ::compress.bat:
   @echo off
   7z a -tzip -mx9 -blah -blah %1.zip

   ::validate.bat:
   @echo off
   7z t %1.zip

   ::delete.bat:
   @echo off
   delete "%1"


   Become one:

   ::main.bat:
   @echo off

   :start
     call compress …
     call validate …
     call delete …
   goto :eof

   :compress
     7z a -tzip -mx9 -blah -blah %1.zip
   goto :eof

   :validate
     7z t %1.zip
   goto :eof

   :delete.bat
     delete "%1"
   goto :eof
   ```
2. You only need [`enableextensions`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959665.aspx) and/or [`enabledelayedexpansion`](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) if you are going to be using them. I don’t know what you have in your batch files, but if you’re not, then you can leave them out.
3. You don’t *have* to use them in the external batch-files if you can them from another one that turns echo off, but it’s just a good habit to include it as a standard header, particularly for batch-files that you could call by themselves (e.g. calling `compress.bat` from the command-prompt manually). There’s very few scenarios where you would specifically want/need to not include it.
4. You *can* use `start /wait`, but simply calling an external file automatically waits for it to return by default, so it should not be necessary. You usually want to use it when calling a GUI program from a batch file. Further, calling `start` complicates passing arguments to the target program more so than simply `call`ing them.
5. More than likely, yes. The loop parameters are local to the `for` loop, so the other batch-file will not see them unless they happen to have a `for` loop, and even then, only in the loop itself:

   ```
   C:\t>type baz.bat
   @for %%a in (1) do call foobar.bat %%a

   C:\t>type foobar.bat
   @echo off
   echo %1
   echo %%a
   for %%a in (1) do echo %%a
   echo %%a

   C:\t>baz.bat

   C:\t>call foobar.bat 1
   1
   %a
   1
   %a

   C:\t>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Been attempting to understand when you can pass `%1`. My understanding is that this is the value inputted by the user. Haven't seen too many examples explaining this clearly. Secondly again I don't have a detailed understand of `enableextensions` and `enabledelayedexpansion`. I had a read of the examples you cited before I posted my question but I only included them because I came across a post noting to use them if calling variables within a file.

Comment: The reason I used `start /wait` was because of my issue at http://superuser.com/questions/465985/run-a-program-in-a-batch-script-and-wait-for-it-to-finish-before-continuing

Comment: What do you mean by `unless they happen to have a for loop`? I would almost all of my batch files have `for` loops in them so I take it that I could run into issues using the same variable names. How do overcome an issue like that if you have numerous `for` loops.

Comment: Re: `%1`, You’re close; `%1` is just the batch-file’s first argument (`argv[1]` if you know C). It can be passed on the command-line by the user, or in a `call` by another batch-file. You don’t pass “%1” itself; you call the target batch-file and add the data you want to pass to the call, then in the *target* batch-file you use `%1` to access that data. You *could* pass %1 from one batch-file to another if you specifically wanted to pass the first file’s (first) argument to the second batch-file, but then in the second one, it *may* not map to `%1`, it may be `%2` or something else.

Comment: Re: `start`, You have to use `start` to call winscp because that’s a separate program that continues to run but returns, so the batch-file continues. By using `start`, the batch-file that called it waits for the *process* to terminate (including any windows it creates). You need to use `start` in the batch file that calls winscp, but not in the batch-file that calls the batch-file that calls winscp because the first batch-file waits for the second one to finish automatically, so if you use start to force the second one to wait for winscp to finish, then the first file is automatically paused.

Comment: Re: extensions. Command-line extensions provide various enhancements, but it sounds like you are not actually using them, so you should be able to safely ignore them for now. The delayed-expansion allows you to use a parameter of a `for` loop in the loop itself which is an advanced concept and from your sample code, it looks like you’re not using it, so you can ignore that as well. As for the loop parameters, like I said, each one is **local to the loop it was defined in**, so no other loops or files ever see them. Look at the results of the call to `foobar.bat` in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks Synetech. That was helpful. I am however confused by what you meant when you said `you call the target batch-file and add the data you want to pass to the call, then in the target batch-file you use %1 to access that data. You could pass %1 from one batch-file to another if you specifically wanted to pass the first file’s (first) argument to the second batch-file, but then in the second one, it may not map to %1, it may be %2 or something else`. Can you give me an example of this?

Comment: Also what do you mean by `continues to run but returns, so the batch-file continues`

Comment: Just ran the example code you posted e.g. `baz.bat` and `foobar.bat` and saw how value from `baz.bat` was passed to `foobar.bat` using `%1` but I don't still get `but then in the second one, it may not map to %1, it may be %2 or something else`. Do you mean that if I wanted to map values from the second batch file to a third, I would have to use `%2` as opposed to `%1`?

Comment: This isn’t the best place to teach batch-programming, but you can see how it all works by making these five batch-files and passing them different arguments to see their results:   **a.bat**: `@echo %1 %2 %3`   **b.bat**: `@call a.bat blah`   **c.bat**: `@call a.bat %1`   **d.bat**: `@call a.bat foo bar %1`   **e.bat**: `@call a.bat %3 %2 %1`

Comment: Thanks. Will run through them. Any chance I could drop you an email for more specific questions?

Comment: You can use the [chat function](http://superuser.com/questions/467653/could-i-centralize-batch-files-more-efficiently/467664#) that appears above the comment box. It’s something of a cross between email and IRC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4672/discussion-between-peanutsmonkey-and-synetech)